# Как можно распространить веб приложение написанное на java?

Tags: java

Я написал веб-приложение (Java 6 + Tomcat 7) для работы с базой данных, т.е. оно состоит из сервлетов, JSP-шников и пачки библиотек.... Мне нужно как то распространить его на другие компьютеры. Но я так понимаю Jar не для веб приложений, а War запускать можно только в контейнере.... Если есть другие способы расскажите о них пожалуйста(ну или ссыль киньте). И еще вопрос: Если я написал приложение на томкате, а перемещу War-архивом его на другой контейнер например oracle, безболезненно ли будет проходить перемещение? Или что то менять нужно?

Comment: В том виде, в котором есть, распространять будет сложно. Я бы посоветовал использовать фреймворк, вроде Spring Boot, у которого контейнер сервлетов встроен внутрь. Такое приложение можно упаковать в jar и ничего, кроме устнановленной JRE на машине не потребуется.

Comment: @coolsv а без spring boot это можно сделать? Я просто spring не использовал никогда и изучать я его буду возможно на следующем проекте, а этот хотелось бы вручную(без фрэймворков) пока собрать. Вроде как можно встроить контейнер в проект типа jetty или того же томката, но как сделать это я не знаю, в интернете есть способ через мавен, но опять же это мне не подходит

Comment: если спринг никак, то советую исопльзовать embedded tomcat вместе со сборщиком вроде maven или gradle. Сборщики это уже прям базовая вещь, от неё точно не стоит отказываться. В теории можно и полностью вручную - выкачать сорцы и подложить внутрь приложения, но это экзотическое и крайне неудобное решение, поэтому хотя бы с maven я советую разобраться уже сейчас.